# How to parse Json from local file?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-json

I want to parse JSON from local file stored in asset folder and set it to recyclerview in android. But recyclerview is not populating.

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with this?
I have tried many answers from here, but its not working.

JSON

```
{
    "box": [
        {
            "text" : "text1 "
        },
        {
            "text" : "text2"
        },
        {
        "text" : "text3"
        },
        ...............
    ]
}
```

CODE

```
private String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
private void RequestJson() {
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.mRecycler);
    List<Box> data=new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray tablelist = json.getJSONArray("box");

        for (int i = 0; i < tablelist.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject AllTable = tablelist.getJSONObject(i);
            Box items2 = new Box();

            items2.setText(AllTable.getString("text"));
            data.add(items2);
        }
        mAdapter = new BoxAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Try some [debugging](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/#startdebug). Set a breakpoint on `items2.setText(AllTable.getString("text"));` and inspect the values of `AllTable` and `tablelist` - Are they populated like you'd expect them to be?

Comment: No they are not. In debug i get something like "Box@342342".

Comment: There are no error or warning @Redman

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: Your above code working fine. Would you please provide your `BoxAdapter` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this things. and make sure data not empty.

```
mAdapter = new BoxAdapter(MainActivity.this, data);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: When i logged the "data", i got something like this"com.app.box.Model.Box@4d3056"

Comment: check your data size like data.size()

Comment: it is 13 as expected, but it increase one by one

Comment: `notifyDatasetChanged()` is not necessary and makes no difference when Adapter is added to the `RecyclerView`

Comment: The problem was with getItemCount. it was set to 0. Thanks for your time.